# Express Patch Method usage

Tags: node.js, api, express, methods, api-design

my question is about the design of an API.

We are about to rebuild our entire API backend infrastructure from Meteor.JS to NodeJS/Express.

Although we found one problem concerning our API.
We used to have Method.Call on Meteor and could define whatever we want using that.

Now we would like to follow some REST principles and therefor we would like to use only GET/POST/PUT/DELETE and PATCH

//Example POST

```
createTournament: async(req, res) => {
  if(!req.body || typeof req.body !== 'object'
    || !req.body.name || typeof req.body.name !== 'string'
    || !req.body.description || typeof req.body.description !== 'string'
    || !req.body.gameId || typeof req.body.gameId !== 'string')
  {
      return res.sendStatus(400);
  }
  const insertId = await (functions.createTournament(
    req.body.name,
    req.body.description,
    req.body.gameId);
  if (insertId) {
    res.status(201).send(insertId);
  } else {
    res.sendStatus(404);
  }
},
```

//My current patch function

```
patch: async(req, res) => {
  if (!req.params
  || !req.params.id  
  || !req.body) {
    res.sendStatus(400);
  }
  const tournament = await functions.patchTournament(req.params.id, req.body);
  res.status(200).send(tournament);
},
```

The problem is that only users with the role admin can patch a gameId, and other users can only patch a description.

This is a lightweight object, since the actual one has about 20 properties to be set.

While using PATCH, we were wondering if it was possible to authorize certain user roles to be able of only editing certain fields.
And how we could do this in a clear and easy to understand manner.

Any help would be really great. If you have any questions feel free to ask me.

Comment: Usually authorization checks are handled in Express middleware.  You examine each incoming request and decide if the user making the request has appropriate permissions for the request they are attempting. If not, you immediately return an error and the actual request handler never gets called. If they do have appropriate permissions for the request, you pass control on to the next item in the chain (which will be either the next middleware or the actual request).

Comment: My question more specific is about patch apis and how to exactly parse the specifi fields a user/moderator/admin would like to update.
Since checking single fields seems like a hassle, and checking by model or some other way would be easier

Comment: I don't think people can help you "specifically" as you request without seeing your actual code - there simply isn't enough info in your question.  If you have field level permissions in your design, then the generic answer is that you must check any field submitted with the patch request to see if the current user is authorized to make that change.  If you're looking for your database to do that work for you, then you'd have to make this a very specific database question where you cite the actual database you're using, show your model, show your code for implementing the patch request, etc...

Comment: If you have implemented your own roles, then you could define a list of fields a given role was allowed to modify, create a role hierarchy and then you could write generic middleware that would take a given role and tell you if the current patch request is allowed or not.  But that middleware would have to look at every field submitted and compare it to the allowable fields for the current user's role.

Comment: @jfriend00 I'll modify my question right now